# matplotlib: put two x-y plots in one

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am using the following codes to plot several data points (xi, yi)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xi = np.array(data_df[['col_A']])
yi = np.array(data_df[['col_B']])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xi, yi)

x = np.linspace(0, 30, 30)
y= np.exp(x*0.16)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want the plot to look like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The code from the question does produce the two plots in a single axes. So it is rather useless to ask about something which is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User subplots to plot more than 1 plots in 1 figure.You need to call plt.show() only once.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xi = np.array(data_df[['col_A']])
yi = np.array(data_df[['col_B']])

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(xi, yi)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
x = np.linspace(0, 30, 30)
y= np.exp(x*0.16)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I mean I just want one plot in one figure. But the ONE plot needs to have both the (xi,yi) and fitted curves.

Comment: Kool then do not call plt.show() 2 times. Call it once all figures are painted at last.

Comment: Thanks. Then for (xi, yi), how do I just plot "points" instead of connecting them?

Comment: Use plt.scatter for first plot.